# In php , How I can delete substring from an array?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am having below array.and I want to delete gupta from the arrayand would like to return remaining array.

```
$array = array('dave gupta', 'stephen gupta', 'rajni goel');
$substring want to delete gupta
```

output required =>

```
$array = array('dave', 'stephen', 'rajni');
```

Thanks for help in advance.

In my actual code

```
$this->Html->link($serv[$index]['Service'] => by this I can getting all the value from the data base.
```

my values are

```
Web Development
Graphic design
App Development
Digital design
```

I want to remove only development and want to fetech rest of the array?

```
echo  urldecode(strtoupper($this->Html->link($serv[$index]['Service']['name'],array('controller' => $serv[$index]['Service']['controller'],
                   'action' => $serv[$index]['Service']['action'],$serv[$index]['Service']['id'],
                   'admin' => false,
                   'plugin' => false),array('class'=>'menuForFooter2'))));
```

Comment: Pseudo-code  , foreach item {string replace})

Comment: If you only want to delete `gupta`, how is it that your last item in the result has been changed?

Comment: Can't post an answer, so take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/YHHDgXNx

Answer (score -1):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will fit in this case.

```
$array = array('dave', 'gupta','stephen', 'gupta','rajni', 'goel');
$output=array_filter($array, function($s){return $s!='gupta';});
```

Comment: That's not what the original array looked like.

Comment: Sorry, then array_map will help: $output=array_map(function($s){ return trim(str_replace('gupta', '', $s));}, $array);

Comment: What array_map and array_filter doing here exactly ?

Comment: **array_map**: apply function on each element of the array; **array_filter**: filter array elements with a testing function

Comment: @DanwuHou FYI, you should be able to edit/improve your own answer whenever you like.